# Attemping to setup Domain NameServers but it doesn't appear to work

Tags: dns, nameserver

I'm having a little trouble setting up my domain redirect. The domain name is registered with Namesco and the hosting is on Wiserhosting. Wiserhosting has provided me nameservers of

- Nameserver 1: ns1.wiserhosting.co.uk
- Nameserver 2: ns2.wiserhosting.co.uk

I configured these into the DNS settings page on Namesco for this domain
as `hostname: www, type:CNAME, result:ns1.wiserhosting.co.uk`. but when I go to the URL I get redirected to `/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` page which simply shows `mu.wiserhosting.co.uk`.

I am finding it weird that I have two Nameservers but am only able to configure one. I get a duplication error if I add the ns2 with another www host. Wiser also provided an IP address of 78.129.233.118 and I've added that as an A record. but still makes no difference.

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong here, and who should I call? Is the redirect not configured correctly, or is it configured but not working when it gets there?

Comment: Where are you making these DNS setting changes, with the company that you registered the domain? What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get the registered domain to forward to the hosting company. the registration was done with namesco. but the actuall hosting is done with wiser (ie. thats where all the files are). I have put these name servers into the DNS configuration for the domain hosting at namesco. I've not done anything Name or DNS related on wiser.

Comment: All you should need to do is provide namesco with the nameservers and add the domain in wiser, I don't understand why the CNAME is needed.

Comment: I have just been and checked through the other options, there is a nameserver tab, and this has 2 fields for my nameserver. I've set the CNAMES back to default and will check it now. I think you were right. me thinks its a case of thinking a simple job is much harder then it is. time will tell. but thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is provide namesco with the nameservers and add the domain into your control panel at your web host (wiser).

You shouldn't need the CNAME record.

Comment: I have done the nameservers config now, but it says it could take 12-24hours, wish I didn't have to wait so long to find out if its all gong to work. in the meantime, why do I need to Add the domain into Cpanel at Wiser? and where would one do this? I have Domain options of Subdomain, Add on Domains, Parked Domains, Redirects, all of which dont appear to offer a "accept this domain from now on option"?

Comment: @Purplemonkey it's difficult to know for sure based on the information I have. Usually if you registered the hosting account with the domain you had purchased all you should need to do is point nameservers and wait, if you're adding a second domain to an existing account then you'll need to use addon domains. You can use www.iptools.com to keep an eye on the changes to your nameservers and to check the routing. It should take a lot less than 24 hours under normal circumstances, but sometimes really does take that long.

Comment: Am actually doing this for a client, they have purchased about 20 domain names on NamesCo, and they registerd the hosting account with the .com name, so that one should be taken care of. But because of all the problems with the incorrect attempt at setting up the name servers, I thought I'd setup the .net name, but from what you say it sounds like I'd have to add the .net name as a addon domain on my host account. I'll give this a go.

Comment: @Purplemonkey that sounds like the right approach - com/net/org usually start resolving pretty quickly once you have the nameservers set up

Comment: It looks like its all working now. I reset the DNS config, then updated the NameServers, which incidently clears the DNS config on NamesCO. I have added a subdomain of one of these domains on wiser and with the nameservers it appears to work fine. thanks for you help.

Comment: @Purplemonkey glad you got it all working, DNS can be a pain in the backside.