# index.html redirecting to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: redirects, vps, cpanel

This problem has been persisting over the last couple of days. I thought I fixed it Friday only to get in on Monday morning and see that cPanel is still giving me issues.

On Friday, all incoming traffic to my `index.html` page were being redirected to `cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`. Upon further investigation, I found that my entire `index.html` code had been overwritten and contained only a single meta tag, which was causing the aforementioned redirect. I re-uploaded the original index page and overwrote the one that was causing the redirects and it seemed to have fixed the problem.

Fast forward to Monday. The problem began happening again and I took the same steps as before to fix it, but now I'm wondering how to permanently stop this from happening. From what I've found, it's related to cPanel. I personally did not make any changes to the server, but there are a few people with access who might have.

I'm on a VPS with my own dedicated IP address. I've been hosting fine for a few months without this problem. The server is runs a traditional LAMP stack.

Comment: Who's your hosting company with the VPS? And what other applications are running other than Apache2?

Comment: @Anagio GoDaddy hosts the VPS, other applications include phpMyAdmin and WHM.

Comment: Andrew there are a few related questions here on the site search here is one http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/26151/10527 not sure if it'll relate to your setup but other people had the same problem with the `cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` appearing rather than there index file. Search that string with double quotes and a few more questions will show up. Since you're on GoDaddy call them they are in the US and tech's are helpful.